# Blackberry 10 Installing .bar file

Tags: c++, qt, qml, blackberry-10

I have only .bar file and its debug token . I want to run it on other device of BlackBerry z10. How should I do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

you need to install debug token to device. Once that is done you can use following command to deploy bar file to device. following command can deploy multiple bar file.

```
./batchbar-deploy ~/Desktop/BARFOLDER 169.254.0.1 DEVICE_DEVELOPMENT_PASSWORD
```

Here 169.254.0.1 is device IP, when you attach it to computer.
Device should be in development mode.

You can use following command too.

```
 ./blackberry-deploy -installapp -package ./BAR_FILE.bar -device 169.254.0.1 -password DEVICE_DEVELOPMENT_PASSWORD
```

You can fine more information [here](http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.kr/2013/05/converting-apk-to-bar-and-deploying-it.html).

Answer (score 1):

here is how i do
1) [download DDPB](http://ddpb.dauden.vn/)

2) switch on development mode of your device

3) open that .bar file in the software

4) connect the device and press install.

Hope it does help.......

Answer (score 0):

1. Drag the .bar file into your qnx editor work-space
2. Now click install button by selecting target device
3. It will run on simulator without any prompt
4. Try it to install by selecting mobile as target device

Comment: If your problem is solved please accept the thread as solution and give up your vote..